# Having issues with Perl compilation

Tags: apache, perl

When I execute a Perl program it is giving errors as below. What could be the issue?

```
Can't find lib in either /apps/cgi/kb or /apps/cgi, stopped at /usr/local/share/perl5/mylib.pm line 22.
Compilation failed in require at www_kb_search_new.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at www_kb_search_new.pl line 4.
```

Comment: Please show your Perl code, especially line 4

Comment: @Borodin, 

below is the line 4

use mylib;

can you just let me know how to update the mylib.pm file, can i update the mylib.pm file???

Comment: There's no reason to believe it's not up to date. What problem are you trying to solve? You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [`mylib`](http://metacpan.org/module/mylib) pragma, which adds to `@INC` the `lib` directory in either the directory where the Perl script is located or its parent

Your Perl file is `/apps/cgi/kb/www_kb_search_new.pl`, so `mylib` is looking for either `/apps/cgi/kb/lib` or `/apps/cgi/lib` and finding neither

If you have your own modules that you want to load then the solution is to create one of these directories and put your modules there. If you are not using any non-standard modules then just remove the `use mylib` statement

Comment: Thanks,I have removed the use mylib and it got executed.

[root@u-downloads-01 kb]# perl www_kb_search_new_QA.pl
Status: 302 Found
Location: http://support.polycom.com/PolycomService/knowledgebase/supportcentral/supportcentral.do?id=m1&searchMode=


but when i try to fetch through apache URL it was extracting the actual script not the result of this script.